# How do I get the name of the type currently held by an `any`?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++17, type-erasure, boost-any

Suppose I have either:

1. A `boost::any` or
2. An `std::any` (and I'm using C++17)

the type of which I don't know. Is it possible for me to print, or get as a string, the name of the type that's being held by the `any`?

**Note:** Even a mangled type name - the kind you get with `typeid(TR).name()` - would be sufficient I can take it from there using `abi::__cxa_demangle`.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace TestNamespace {
  class Test {
    int x{ 0 };
    int y{ 1 };
  };
}

int main()
{       
  any thing = TestNamespace::Test();

  cout << thing.type().name() << endl;
  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:
`class TestNamespace::Test`

Oh and at least in msvc, the type_info for a std template library class looks a lot uglier than say `std::string` (looks like: `class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >`)